# Angular 2: fetch as google doesn't render correctly page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have Angular 2 application running on **myDomain.com**. Default route is **/home**.

In Google Console, I run **Fetch as Google** with the following result:

- fetching **myDomain.com** -> **/home** page is rendered **- EXPECTED RESULT**
- fetching **myDomain.com/anyRoute** -> **/home** page is rendered **- ERROR RESULT**, I expect that **/anyRoute** page will be rendered

So it seems that Google is able to read and correctly render my JavaScript, but have issues to route inside my app.

Here is my Route config:

```
export const routes: ModuleWithProviders =

             RouterModule.forRoot(router, 
                     {useHash: false, initialNavigation: false });
```

I am NOT using (and I don't want) any kind of the server side rendering.

(Since this could be Angular 2 specific problem (and not general SPA problem), I am posting it rather here.)

Comment: As far as I'm aware google only follows actual anchor tags on the page. You can add a sitemap.xml and see if that helps it navigate through your app. If you have a node app you could use prerender.io also to allow it to read your meta tags properly.

Comment: I will try adding the sitemap, but in this case, I am basically telling Google. Render myDomain.com/anyRoute. So I am making him aware of this route -  same as sitemap would do.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure if the google robot can go to it regardless if you tell it to. I've had lots of issues with crawlers and stuff and managed to solve it using prerender and a sitemap. So hopefully it'll solve it for you too.